# Цикличность изменения значений параметров действия

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В представлении **Home** присутствует элемент который вызывает метод **ChangeValue()**, который в свою очередь меняет параметр **value** представления **Home** и формирует переход на него. Первый вызов успешен, последующие нет.

```
public ActionResult Home(bool value)
{
    return View();
}

public RedirectToRouteResult ChangeValue()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home", new
        {
            value = !Convert.ToBoolean(RouteData.Values["value"])
        });
}
```

Comment: "Первый вызов успешен, последующие нет." - что это значит, сударь? Ознакомьте нас с Вашим пониманием "успеха", пожалуйста.

Comment: При первом вызове значение value изменяется в противоположное, при последующих вызовах оно остаётся прежним. То есть не принимает противоположное значение новому (false -> true, true -> true)

Comment: "При ... вызове" - как происходит "вызов"?

Comment: @Url.Action("ChangeValue", "Home")

Comment: Во время выполнения `ChangeValue()` в `RouteData.Values` нет `"value"`.

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: Что исправить :)? Вы привели неработающий код, который делает непонятно что. Что Вы хотите сделать (желательно понятное объяснение человеческим языком)?

Comment: Получить значение параметра value представления Home, изменить его на противоположный и запустить представление с изменённым параметром.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Url.Action("ChangeValue", "Home", new { value = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["value"] })
```

Comment: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'RouteData.Values'

Comment: @Solvent Пардон, писал ответ прямо сюда.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо Вам!